# No styling from tailwindcss on MUI

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui, tailwind-css

I can't get any styling from tailwindcss to go on my MUI button. I am using babel and webpack. And the npm run dev script is "webpack --mode development --watch"

tailwind.css

```css
module.exports = {
  content: ["./src/**/*.{js, jsx, ts, tsx}", "./templates/**/*.{html}"],
  important: '#root',
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

App.css

```css
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```

App.js

```
import "./App.css"
import { StyledEngineProvider } from '@mui/material/styles'
import CssBaseline from '@mui/material/CssBaseline'

// ...
<StyledEngineProvider injectFirst>
  <CssBaseline />
  <Button>Click me</Button>
</StyledEngineProvider>
```

Comment: related: https://mui.com/material-ui/integrations/interoperability/#tailwind-css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply change the following codes in your App.css and it will work.

from this

```
@tailwind components;

@tailwind utilities;
```

to this

```
@import "tailwindcss/components";

@import "tailwindcss/utilities";
```

Rest of the codes remain same. Only the above needs to be changed and you're good to go. This usually happens in tailwind v3.

Hope this answer helps you.

Comment: Do you have a guide for how to properly add tailwindcss to a webpack react and mui project? There are so many different ways and I tried all of them but to no avail so I gave up but after changing the App.css what do I do to compile the css etc?

Comment: Nothing differs. You just follow this official guide but instead use the above tailwind directives. It would work.  https://tailwindcss.com/docs/guides/create-react-app. I've had the same problem and the above changes fixed the issue.